# import data from web to google sheet with user authentication

Tags: authentication, google-sheets, passwords

I want to import data from a specific web page to google sheet that requires user authentication.

I tried with `importhtXML` and `XPATH` but doesn't work.

I read that I need a script but don't know how to do that and how to connect it to google sheet.

How can i do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!. Usually you will not get a good response unless you post some code you have tried. If you have never used Google Scripts before you need to do a tutorial first. If you search on "google sheets scripts tutorial" there are lots to choose from.

Comment: Welcome. How did you get on with importing your data into Google sheets? Did you manage to resolve things, or are you still looking for assistance?